# ftp_put(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary. Why it gives me this warning?

Tags: php, ftp

I've the following code in PHP:

```
$connection = @ftp_connect (IP of the server, 21);
ftp_login ($connection, User in FTP, Password in FTP);

ftp_pasv ($connection, true);
ftp_put ($connection, Remote File, Local file, FTP_BINARY);
```

I create the connection to FTP and I can login, but the **ftp_put** function always uploads an empty file with the warning:

```
Warning:  ftp_put(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary
```

However when I change FTP_BINARY to FTP_ASCII the file gets to upload but due to "special characters" (it's a jpg photo), the content it's not the same as "original file". The question is:

Why not work with FTP_BINARY and show me this warning?

Comment: Well it is just a warning where is the problem ?

Comment: The remote file uploaded to the ftp is empty... that's a problem, don't you think? I try with ftp_fput() and ensuring that the local file being read contains information, but I have the same problem.

Comment: can you please check permission this is normally happens when you do not have right permission on that directory. Do not forget to give permissions to Apache Server because he is writing to that directory

Comment: When I change FTP_BINARY to FTP_ASCII the file gets to upload but the content is not the same as original file (it's an jpg photo)

Comment: what is the return value of ftp_put

Comment: Hi Mian, thanks for your help. The return value of ftp_put is false (with FTP_BINARY)

Comment: Some hosting does not provide FTP access unless you have dedicated check ftp access with hosting

Comment: However when I change FTP_BINARY to FTP_ASCII the file gets to upload but due to "special characters" (it's a jpg photo), the content it's not the same as "original file".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14735/discussion-between-mian-khurram-ijaz-and-doctore)

Comment: @Mian: In PHP, a warning is pretty serious business.  On the scale of badness it's just shy of an error...and errors kill the script.  Warnings are meant to tell you about stuff that isn't fatal on its own, but almost certainly isn't what you wanted to happen -- and is pretty sure to cause an error later on if left unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

These warnings can appear either with a ftp_put() or a ftp_get(), in FTP_BINARY or FTP_ASCII:

- Warning:  ftp_get(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary
- Warning:  ftp_get(): TYPE is now ASCII
- Warning:  ftp_put(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary
- Warning:  ftp_put(): TYPE is now ASCII

You can mute them by using @ftp_put or @ftp_get, but in case of "get", the destination file is systematically deleted without being replaced.

The passive mode must correct them when placed before the ftp_put() or ftp_get():

```
 ftp_pasv($connection, true);
```